# Belgium Tripel with Sorachi Ace Hops

Tags: hops, belgian

Good evening, home-brewing community!

I'm seeking a quick advise. I'm brewing (or attempting at least) a Belgium Tripel. I'm pretty solved on grains. Still trying to figure out the hops.

So, I plan to put 1oz Perle @60min, 1oz Saaz @30min... and I have 1oz of Sorachi. Would it make my tripel out of style if I use Sorachi like @5 mins? Or even break by 0.5oz to dryhop my tripel with it after 6 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BJCP's current draft guidelines seem to say ([big pdf](http://www.bjcp.org/docs/2014%20BJCP%20Style%20Guidelines%20(DRAFT).pdf)) that various types of Belgian beers in categories 21B (Specialty IPA, scroll down for Belgian Specialty IPA) or 26C (Belgian Tripel) should use European hops. In  particular, for 26C they say: "A low yet distinctive spicy, floral, sometimes perfumy hop character is usually found."

So in regards to 'style' it seems that Sorachi Ace isn't a good match.

Beyond that, we get into opinion. I think Duvel's most recent triple hop used some Sorachi Ace, so if you can get some of that beer, compare it to the regular stuff, you can an idea what it does that context.

Comment: Thanks. Keeping the style is sort of important. I wanna enter a local competition, and that would totally declassify the style. I'll use Styrian Golding instead, which will keep it within 26C boundaries. Correction, I think this year BJCP goes with 2008 guidance, which is 18C...